# Ruby : unable to find strings with special character in a file

Tags: ruby, regex, escaping

I'm trying to check if string(s) are present in a file using the below option: (tried in IRB)

```
File.readlines("E:/nano/ABC.txt").grep(/Digital/).any?
=> true
```

gives me true, so string is available but if I check for ids like below

```
File.readlines("E:/nano/ABC.txt").grep(/ncr\abc_efg_dev/).any?
=> false
```

or

```
File.readlines("E:/nano/ABC.txt").grep(/ncr\yui30n/).any?
=> false
```

it's giving `false` and it's unable to identify the string even though it's present in the file. I'm not sure how to check the existence of the strings - `'ncr\jx8go5'` or  `'ncr\atxe5t'`

**ABC.txt**

```
# Digital created on July 2016
# Digital Owner: John Cena (jxcgo)
# Digital access: create delete access

[groups]
first = ncr\abc_efg_dev, ncr\abc_efg_test, ncr\jx8go5, ncr\atxe5t
digital_owner = ncr\yui30n, ncr\bhyrl4
```

Comment: To match a backslash literally, you have to escape it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the back-slash. For example:

```
File.readlines("E:/nano/ABC.txt").grep(/ncr\\abc_efg_dev/).any?
```

Or for a fully generic solution, you can use [Regexp#escape](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-c-escape):

```
search_string = 'ncr\abc_efg_dev'
File
  .readlines("E:/nano/ABC.txt")
  .grep(Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(search_string)))
  .any?
```

This is because, for example, `\a` is a special character called the [Bell code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character).

Other examples include `\n` (newline), `\t` (tab), `\f` (form feed), `\v` (vertical tab), `\r` (a carriage return), `\s` (any white-space character), `\b` (a backspace or word boundary, depending on context), ...

Long story short, you should always escape `\` in a regular expression (or any double-quoted string in ruby!), unless you are intentionally using it to denote a special character.

Comment: Thank you, how to escape if it is a variable substitution  scenario. ( inside a loop)
Eg, I'm reading string values 1 by 1 from a different file and check if that string is present in any of the files inside a folder.

values.txt

`ncr\yui30n 
 ncr\bhyrl4
ncr\abc_efg_dev`

check - ncr\yui30n is present in any of the files in a directory inside a foreach loop, then check ncr\bhyrl4 is present in any of the files. so on..

Comment: For a fully generic solution, you can use [Regexp#escape](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-c-escape): `Regexp.new(Regexp.escape('ncr\yui30n'))`. However, this is admittedly a little clunky... If you are always just searching for a literal string (i.e. you don't really need to use a regex at all), you could also consider [using `String#include?`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8414129/1954610).

Comment: Thanks much. I'm not able to replace the given string in multiple files one by one in a loop. sorry I know its not ethical to ask here but I'm not sure why the target files are getting modified

below is my code


`value=File.open('E:\nano\out.txt').read
value.each_line do |line|
    line.chomp!
   Dir.glob("E:\nano\*.txt") do |file_name|
   text = File.read(file_name)
   replace = text.gsub(Regexp.escape("#{line}"), "")
   File.open(file_name, "w") { |file| file.puts replace }
 end
end`

Comment: I fixed it , there was some incorrect folder name. thanks for ur time:)